# Facebook business page link on my website generates security check

Tags: facebook, relative-urls

I have a link on my website to my FB business page, it is the exact URL for the FB page, but whenever I try to access that link FB throws up a security check.

I'm making an attempt to use FB to promote my business and FB is blocking any visitors accessing or making it very hard for them to access the page.

It is not something that used to happen, just recently, and it sometimes feels like I should remove the link - it is counter productive.

The link is

```
<a href="//www.facebook.com/pages/example/example" target="_blank">
```

Also tried changing the link to after going on FB developers and they said the link must be 'explicit'

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/example/example" target="_blank">
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I should answer my own question because I think I've solved the puzzle.

We are on a new ISP provider with dynamically assigned IP addresses (where previously we had our own static IP address which did not change) and it turns out that the IP addresses we are currently being assigned are on a blacklist - so we are being seen as insecure by FB.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried asking others to test this for the first time? If Facebook sees you clicking this link repetitively, they may view you as a spam bot and therefore require further security confirmation.

Alternatively, it could be due to your website being new or having low traffic. Once traffic picks up on the site, Facebook can determine that it is secure and will often remove the security check.